# chronological list of points earned

Tags: support, reputation

I keep a text file record of my points earned in various SE QA forums.
The points icon just showed up in the Unix & Linux header telling me I earned 10 more. But my total points is 20 greater than the last time I recorded it.

While this is certainly not a problem, I don't see any way to figure out where the other 10 points came from. The rest of the entries for points don't seem to show anything about when they were earned.

This has happened to me a number of times across several SE QAs although I think I have recorded my points earned every time I have seen a points earned icon.

Is there some way to get a list of points earned in chronological order so I can see what I have missed?

When I get points, especially for an old answer, I often revisit it and see if it needs updating, so this is not purely a vanity request.

Answer (score 5):

There's this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/reputation, which, despite appearing to be a generic link, uses your current credentials to show your reputation changes. To help understand the format, please see [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)